# Creating procedure won't recognize DB

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create and execute a procedure that creates some tables. It won't recognize my database.

```
USE [db1]
go
create procedure version_1 as
    update db1 
        set ver=1
        where ver=0;
    create table Staff_Titles(
        title nvarchar(100) not null,
        title_description nvarchar(200) null,
[..]
go
```

It compiles even though the db1 from update db1 is underlined. So is ver=1 and ver=0. After I try to execute it, it says

> invalid object name

at USE [DB1] again even though, it's inside the stored procedures...

I tried refreshing the database, I tried looking for Edit -> IntelliSense but I can't find it, I tried Ctrl + shift + R, nothing worked.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you already have a database called `db1` ? If you do have a database called `db1` do you also have a table called `db1` inside it?

Comment: Yes. My procedures are stored in the db1

Comment: Show use the complete procedure, this should work as it is, unless you are doing something unusual down the line once you have created this table inside the procedure.

Comment: whats written in line 4 in your proc?

Comment: if you have no db1 or vtrak table, what are you trying to do with that update?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm trying to create tables inside my VTrack database using procedures

Comment: Did you just recently create db1?

Comment: Yea. I created the database just before executing the query and running the procs. I refreshed the database after I executed the query

Comment: I added a possible answer about clearing intellisense cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IntelliSense is telling you that it can't find a table called db1 in the db1 database.  Make sure the table exists or if it's in a different schema, make sure to include the schema, like this:

```
update db1.schmaname.db1 
    set ver=1
    where ver=0;
```

If you are trying to store version data, you have to add a table and a field to store this information.  You can not update fields on a database, as there are no fields directly at the database level.  You can create a table called "Versions" with a field called "ver".

```
CREATE TABLE Versions
(
    [Ver] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Versions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Ver ASC)
)
```

Then when you run the procedure it could insert a record to indicate that the tables have been updated with that version.  Something like this:

```
insert into Versions
values (1)
```

Then if you ever need to query for the latest version you could use:

```
select max(Ver) Ver from Versions
```

Comment: But... I don't have a db1 table. I have a db1 database. My procedures are creating the tables.

Comment: You can only update tables, not a database.  What are you trying to update?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm trying to create tables inside my VTrack database using procedures

Comment: Ok this did it for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and clear the intellisense cache if you "just" created that Database. Use the keystroke `Ctrl-Shift-R` or `Ctrl-R`.

Comment: I mentioned that I already tried refreshing InteliSense and it's not doing anything. I don't even have that option in Edit. Tried it again and nothing

Comment: I just tested it out on a DB not tables and it works the same for me - Ctrl-Shift-R...the red squiggly underneath goes away.

Comment: Oh lol, nevermind, I see this was a mixup between table and database declarations.